# How to display $wpdb->insert_id; value on redirected page

Tags: database

I have created two pages **Checkout Page** & **Payment Page**.

On **Checkout Page** I added following code:

```
<?php

  if(isset($_POST['submit_now'])) {
        global $wpdb;
$wpdb->insert( 
    'wp9c_treetweet', 
    array( 
        'name' => $_POST['aname'], 
        'roll' => $_POST['aroll']
    ), 
    array( 
        '%s', 
        '%d'
    ) 
);
$lastid = $wpdb->insert_id;
wp_redirect( home_url( '/payment/' ) );
exit;
}
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<form action="" method="POST" id="addcourse">
<label>Student Name:<input type="text" name="aname" size="30"></label>
<label>Roll:<input type="text" name="aroll" size="30"></label>
<input type="hidden" name="insert" value="<?php echo $_SESSION[$lastid]; ?>">

<input type="submit" name="submit_now" id="addcoursesubmit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And on **Payment Page** I have added following code:

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['aname']; ?>
<?php echo $_SESSION['aroll']; ?>
<?php echo $_SESSION['insert']; ?>
```

After subbmiting the form the values of Name and Roll is getting displayed on the **Payment page** but the value of **'insert'** i.e. `$wpdb->insert_id;` is not getting displayed.

Plz help me out with a solution. Thanks.

Comment: where you put session_start();?

Comment: @Jevuska I have added it in functions.php

Comment: You need to put your session last id before your page redirected.

Comment: @Jevuska can u plz help me by modifying my code. As I m confused. Thanks

Comment: it is not clear about `$_SESSION[$lastid];` in your form, where `$lastid` value come from. But If you need get the value of `$lastid = $wpdb->insert_id;` you need to create a session on it, i.e `$_SESSION['insert'] =  $wpdb->insert_id`

Comment: @Jevuska +1 That's only I want. Big Thanks dear. Can we use this value as a unique order_id in shopping cart or it may create any duplicate issue

Comment: it depend on your db table setup, just make it sure the id is unique when insert data.

Comment: @Jevuska One last question. If 2 customers processed their orders at the same time & same moment. will each customer will get the same order Id or the order id against which there product got register.

Comment: Hmm.  I would like to refer the answer into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557571/how-does-mysql-deal-with-multiple-inserts-at-the-same-time-with-unique-values